# Should I Use Base64 or Unicode for Storing Hashes & Salts?

Tags: encryption, unicode

I have never worked on the security side of web apps, as I am just out of college. Now, I am looking for a job and working on some websites on the side, to keep my skills sharp and gain new ones. One site I am working on is pretty much copied from the [original `MEAN` stack](https://github.com/meanjs/mean) from the guys that created it, but trying to understand it and do things better where I can.

To compute the hash & salt, the creators used PBKDF2. I am not interested in hearing about arguments for or against PBKDF2, as that is not what this question is about. They seem to have used buffers for everything here, which I understand is a common practice in `node`. What I am interested in are their reasons for using `base64` for the buffer encoding, rather than simply using `UTF-8`, which is an option with the buffer object. Most computers nowadays can handle many of the characters in Unicode, if not all of them, but the creators could have chosen to encode the passwords in a subset of Unicode without restricting themselves to the 65 characters of `base64`.

By "the choice between encoding as `UTF-8` or `base64`", I mean transforming the binary of the hash, computed from the password, into the given encoding. `node.js` specifies a couple ways to encode binary data into a Buffer object. From the documentation page for the Buffer class:

```
Pure JavaScript is Unicode friendly but not nice to binary data. When dealing with TCP
streams or the file system, it's necessary to handle octet streams. Node has several
strategies for manipulating, creating, and consuming octet streams.

Raw data is stored in instances of the Buffer class. A Buffer is similar to an array
of integers but corresponds to a raw memory allocation outside the V8 heap. A Buffer
cannot be resized.
```

What the Buffer class does, as I understand it, is take some binary data and calculate the value of each 8 (usually) bits. It then converts each set of bits into a character corresponding to its value in the encoding you specify. For example, if the binary data is `00101100` (8 bits), and you specify `UTF-8` as the encoding, the output would be `,` (a comma). This is what anyone looking at the output of the buffer would see when looking at it with a text editor such as `vim`, as well as what a computer would "see" when "reading" them. The Buffer class has several encodings available, such as `UTF-8`, `base64`, and `binary`.

I think they felt that, while storing any `UTF-8` character imaginable in the hash, as they would have to do, would not phase most modern computers, with their gigabytes of RAM and terabytes of space, actually *showing* all these characters, as they may want to do in logs, etc., would freak out users, who would have to look at weird Chinese, Greek, Bulgarian, etc. characters, as well as control characters, like the `Ctrl` button or the `Backspace` button or even beeps. They would never really need to make sense of any of them, unless they were experienced users testing PBKDF2 itself, but the programmer's first duty is to not give any of his users a heart attack. Using `base64` increases the overhead by about a third, which is hardly worth noting these days, and decreases the character set, which does nothing to decrease the security. After all, computers are written completely in binary. As I said before, they could have chosen a different subset of Unicode, but `base64` is already standard, which makes it easier and reduces programmer work.

Am I right about the reasons why the creators of this repository chose to encode its passwords in `base64`, instead of all of Unicode? Is it better to stick with their example, or should I go with Unicode or a larger subset of it?

Comment: Why would anyone be showing the users what the password was? The purpose of hashing the password is to convert it to an unreadable state so no one knows what the plaintext version was.

Comment: I meant showing the *hash* of the password. I will change it to be clearer.

Comment: Why would anyone show the hash of the password to anyone?

Comment: In logs, I suppose. I'm trying to figure out why they wouldn't want to use the full character set of Unicode, and having to show it to people is the only reason I could think of.

Comment: Not at all. I am not asking whether to store the salt in the database, I am asking what encoding to use to store it (and the hash).

Comment: And this is why I love glibc2 crypt. I never have to roll my own weird password/salt/workfactor storage format.

Comment: The continuous confusion between UTF-8, Unicode and raw binary data in this post is making kittens cry... :-(

Comment: [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) (contrary to base64) is not an encoding of (general) binary data, it is an encoding of [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) characters!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is a fundamental, security-related reason to store as Base64 rather than Unicode: the hash may contain the byte value "0", used by many programming languages as an end-of-string marker.

If you store your hash as Unicode, you, another programmer, or some library code you use may treat it as a string rather than a collection of bytes, and compare using `strcmp()` or a similar string-comparison function.  If your hash contains the byte value "0", you've effectively truncated your hash to just the portion before the "0", making attacks much easier.

Base64 encoding avoids this problem: the byte value "0" cannot occur in the encoded form of the hash, so it doesn't matter if you compare encoded hashes using `memcmp()` (the right way) or `strcmp()` (the wrong way).

This isn't just a theoretical concern, either: there have been multiple cases of code for checking digital signatures using `strcmp()`, greatly weakening security.

Comment: Thank you @Mark, great answer. I understand why this is a serious concern, but couldn't you restrict it to a slightly larger subset of Unicode than `base64`, as I hinted in my question?

Comment: Even ignoring the issue of byte value "0", UTF-8 isn't a very efficient way of encoding binary data.  Only the first 128 byte values can be expressed as single-byte UTF-8 characters; the rest are 2, 3, or 4 bytes.  For example, the byte value 11111111 becomes the UTF-8 value 11000011 10111111, occupying two bytes; this gives an average 50% expansion to binary data as compared to Base64's 33%.  If you want more compact storage than Base64 provides, you could try [Ascii85](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85) at only a 25% expansion, but Base64 has more widespread support.

Comment: Wow, I need to do more research on encodings. I read the `Joel on Code` on "the absolute minimum everyone must know about encodings" or whatever, but it didn't go over `UTF-8` having 50% overhead. Thanks for that.

Comment: UTF-8's overhead is variable.  If you're storing English text, it's 0%, while a few percent overhead is typical for other European languages.  50% is the statistically-typical overhead for storing binary data (if all the byte values are less than 128, the overhead is 0; if they're all greater, the overhead is 100%).  Obscure scripts such as Linear B or Deseret can see as much as 300% overhead compared to a dedicated encoding.

Comment: one more question: If we store the password itself as a buffer, which Mongoose allows, and return it as a buffer, both with encoding UTF-8, do the same ramifications apply? I know you can just change it back to UTF-8 later on, but you can do the same if it's stored as base64.

Comment: You're still trying to use UTF8 encoding on what is binary data, that makes no sense. There is no string of characters that need encoding.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich, if you are talking about the buffer, this encodes binary data as something else, usually a string. Therefore, you are in effect encoding a string of characters, it's just they started as binary. Something like that.

Comment: @Mark: If a system uses UTF-8, base64 or base85 are probably the most practical storage formats.  If a system uses two octets per character, those formats are absurdly inefficient (using eight octets to hold three), but I'm not aware of any standard for any better encoding.  Personally, I like base85 (since it handles data in 32-bit chunks rather than 24-bit chunks) but base64 is more common.

Comment: @trysis The difference between **encoding**, **decoding**, and **"an encoding"** can be a little confusing when you're working with a string encoding, such as UTF-8. (Even more so when you want to do something out of the ordinary with it!) Normally, using **the encoding** UTF-8, you can **encode** a string, which gives you binary data, or **decode** binary data, which gives you a string. The `toString` method of `Buffer` (http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end) says that it "decodes and returns a string from buffer data".

Comment: @DanGetz, so what is a buffer encoded with in the first place? It's binary data, yet you encode it like a string. So is it a string, a binary blob, or something else entirely?

Comment: @trysis The buffer contains binary data (normally thought of as a byte string or binary blob). It can be *constructed* from a character string and an encoding. "String" is normally understood to mean "character string", not "byte string".

Comment: UTF-8 still has the issue that you can't just use arbitrary byte sequences; there are many byte sequences that are not well-formed. (see my answer)

Answer (score 56):

A hash value is a sequence of *bytes*. This is binary information. It is **not** a sequence of characters.

UTF-8 is an encoding for turning sequences of characters into sequences of bytes. Storing a hash value "as UTF-8" makes no sense, since it is already a sequence of bytes, and not a sequence of characters.

Unfortunately, many people have took to the habit of considering a byte as some sort of character in disguise; it was at the basis of the C programming language and still infects some rather modern and widespread frameworks such as Python. However, only confusion and sorrow lie down that path. The usual symptoms are people wailing and whining about the dreadful "character zero" -- meaning, a *byte* of value 0 (a perfectly fine value for a byte) that, turned into a character, becomes the special character that serves as end-of-string indicator in languages from the C family. This confusion can even lead to **vulnerabilities** (the zero implying, for the comparison function, an earlier-than-expected termination).

Once you have understood that binary is binary, the problem becomes: how are we to handle and store our hash value ? In particular in JavaScript, a language that is known to be especially poor at handling binary values. The solution is an encoding that turns the bytes into characters, not just any character, but a very small subset of well-behaved characters. This is called [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). Base64 is a generic scheme for encoding bytes into character strings that don't include problematic characters (no zero, only ASCII printable characters, excluding all the control characters and a few others such as quotes).

Not using Base64 would imply assuming that JavaScript can manage an arbitrary sequence of bytes as if it was just "normal characters", and that is simply not true.

Comment: Node's Buffer object can encode binary blobs as UTF-8, as well as Base64. This is what I was referring to.

Comment: @Tom: Is this one of the many reasons why client-side crypto is really a bad idea? I would really much like to hear your thoughts about client-side cryptography (its advantages, disadvantages, etc.). The only related article that I was able to find is: [Matasano's article on "Javascript crypto can be harmful"](http://matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/).

Comment: _JavaScript_ is poor at crypto. Client-side cryptography is fine but raises the delicate issue of having the implementation on the client side. In a Web context, it is much easier to do everything on a server, and manage the client browser as a mere display device.

Comment: "and still infects some rather modern and widespread frameworks such as Python" - only up to Python 2. Python 3 is a poster child in this respect and strictly separates string objects from byte objects, which is one of the reasons I think Python 3 is a huge improvement over Python 2.

Comment: C didn't specify how many bits was in a char, so it would have been perfectly valid to create a compiler in which a char was 32 bits. Such a compiler would basically have had native UTF-32 support. In python there are distinct types for strings of bytes and strings of characters, as long as one doesn't use the wrong of those two types, there is absolutely no problem handling both types cleanly in python. The problem comes when you need to work with code that did mix them up, because then the code will work fine with ASCII characters but break on anything else.

Comment: TL;DR: UTF-8 encodes characters to bytes, base64 encodes bytes to characters. Characters != bytes.

Comment: It will not "encode bytes as UTF-8" but it will "construct UTF-8 string from bytes". Dont use it for binary data.

Comment: Just a note for completeness: Strings in JavaScript are not null-terminated. Possible resulting inaccuracy in the reply: JavaScript could be considered to be a C family language as its syntax is derived from C.

Comment: @eckes: but what does exactly mean to "construct UTF-8 string from bytes"?

Comment: @pabouk That's actually called *character decoding*. You assume that the bytes are the UTF-8 encoding of a string and then you decode them back again. If it never was an encoded string at the first place, then the "fun" starts, especially since many runtimes (even including Java :( ) simply leave out or replace unprintable characters, leading to information loss.

Answer (score 13):

This is an easy answer, since there are an abundance of byte sequences which are not well-formed UTF-8 strings. The most common one is a continuation byte (0x80-0xbf) that is not preceded by a leading byte in a multibyte sequence (0xc0-0xf7); bytes 0xf8-0xff aren't valid either.

So these byte sequences are not valid UTF-8 strings:

- 0x80
- 0x40 0xa0
- 0xff
- 0xfe
- 0xfa

If you want to encode arbitrary data as a string, use a scheme that allows it. Base64 is one of those schemes.

---

An addtional point: you might think to yourself, well, I don't really care whether they're well-formed UTF-8 strings, I'm never going to use the data as a string, I just want to hand this byte sequence to store for later.

The problem with that, is if you give an arbitrary byte sequence to an application expecting a UTF-8 string, and it is not well-formed, the application is not obligated to make use of this byte sequence. It might reject it with an error, it might truncate the string, it might try to "fix" it.

So don't try to store arbitrary byte sequences as a UTF-8 string.

Answer (score 4):

Base64 is better, but consider a websafe base64 alphabet for transport. Base64 can conflict with querystring syntax.

Another option you might consider is using hex. Its longer but seldom conflicts with any syntax.

Comment: Better keep to the standardized name and call it [base64url](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4648#page-7). Hex is mostly useful if you want to have a look at the byte values, base 64 obfuscates them for human consumption.